# Convert sql rows to single row multiple columns data

Tags: sql

I have this structure in table

```
TYPE    DATE        AMOUNT  ID
--------------------------------
B       30.6.2019   15       1
B       30.11.2019  20       1      
C       22.12.2019  17       1  
B       30.6.2019   15       2
B       30.11.2019  20       2      
C       22.12.2019  17       2
```

and i need it in flat one row multiple columns structure

```
TYPE1 DATE1     AMOUNT1 TYPE2 DATE2      AMOUNT2 TYPE3 DATE3      AMOUNT3      ID
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
B     30.6.2019 15      B     30.11.2019 20      C     22.12.2019 17             1
B     30.6.2019 15      B     30.11.2019 20      C     22.12.2019 17             2
```

Please help with the query.

Comment: Please could someone help with the query

Comment: Oracle and mysql are two different database products, pls tag your question with the one you actually use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, You can use the `PIVOT` as follows:

```
SQL> -- Sample data
SQL> WITH YOUR_TABLE(TYPE,"DATE",AMOUNT,ID) AS
  2  (
  3  SELECT 'B',       TO_DATE('30.06.2019','DD.MM.RRRR'),   15,       1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'B',       TO_DATE('30.11.2019','DD.MM.RRRR'),   20,       1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'C',       TO_DATE('22.12.2019','DD.MM.RRRR'),   17,       1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 'B',       TO_DATE('30.06.2019','DD.MM.RRRR'),   15,       2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 'B',       TO_DATE('30.11.2019','DD.MM.RRRR'),   20,       2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  8  SELECT 'C',       TO_DATE('22.12.2019','DD.MM.RRRR'),   17,       2 FROM DUAL )
  9  -- Your query starts from here
 10  SELECT * FROM (
 11  SELECT T.*,
 12         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY "DATE") AS RN
 13    FROM YOUR_TABLE T
 14  ) PIVOT (
 15  MAX ( TYPE ) AS TYPE, MAX ( "DATE" ) AS "DATE", MAX ( AMOUNT ) AS AMOUNT
 16  FOR RN IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
 17  );

        ID 1 1_DATE      1_AMOUNT 2 2_DATE      2_AMOUNT 3 3_DATE      3_AMOUNT
---------- - --------- ---------- - --------- ---------- - --------- ----------
         1 B 30-JUN-19         15 B 30-NOV-19         20 C 22-DEC-19         17
         2 B 30-JUN-19         15 B 30-NOV-19         20 C 22-DEC-19         17

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try a pivot query along with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY "DATE") rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN TYPE   END) AS TYPE1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN "DATE" END) AS DATE1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN AMOUNT END) AS AMOUNT1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN TYPE   END) AS TYPE2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN "DATE" END) AS DATE2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN AMOUNT END) AS AMOUNT2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN TYPE   END) AS TYPE3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN "DATE" END) AS DATE3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN AMOUNT END) AS AMOUNT3,
    ID
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    ID
ORDER BY
    ID;
```

Comment: Hi, This didnt work. It always gives output in TYPE1 AMOUNT1 and DATE1

Comment: I disagree with your comment.  My answer should be working for you.

Comment: Thanks. I tweaked a bit. It worked for me. Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks and same to you. I checked the answer. :)

Comment: Can you help with this one also ?

[{"clientId":165,"price":125},{"clientId":180,"price":200}]

I want a oracle query where i can fetch clientprice based on the clientid. eg, if clientid=165 then price.

Comment: Great.  Ask a new question `:-)`